# What are these thin boards resting on interior wall top plate for?

Tags: drywall, ceiling, framing, attic

I am trying to figure out what these two thin (1x4?) boards being used for in my attic. As you can see in the second picture, they are running parallel to the roof trusses, and on top of the interior wall I am planning on taking out. My first thought is that they are being used to support the ceiling drywall together where two pieces join? If so, what will happen if I remove the interior wall that is supporting these two boards. What can I do to prevent the drywall from falling?

These two boards run the entire length of the top plate, parallel to the wall and roof trusses.

[image: two boards resting on double top plate]

[image: Picture showing boards are in between trusses.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're correct. They're just drywall backing where the span from the adjacent truss is too great to let it float.

The drywall will not fall. You can remove the backing and the wall. When you complete your re-framing you'll need to add backing back in where appropriate.

If you're simply removing that wall, do the demolition, then float boards on each edge of the drywall (half inch plywood or one-by lumber work well), screw them in place through the drywall, then add your 3-1/2" drywall filler strip.

Comment: Thank you, that goes right along with what I was hoping to hear. My only question is; wouldn't adding the plywood or one-by lumber to the edge of the drywall add weight to that seam and cause it to bow downward? Instead of adding floating boards on top, should I span them perpendicular and screw them into the trusses?

Comment: No. The two sheets of drywall, plus the backing, plus your tape joint, essentially result in a rigid system that will span 22-1/2" just fine. It's done a million times a day in remodel projects.